# BluetoothAdapter variable not being found?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello I am working on an Android BLE project and I am running into this problem where I can't check if the `BluetoothAdapter` variable is null? Why is that. It should be fairly straight forward? Did I forget to import something?

[image: Error I am getting]

Comment: Did you `import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;`?

Comment: yes I did. I imported all the libraries. If I didn't  `BluetoothAdapter `would be shown as red.

Comment: Still not working? I have written similar code without any problems. Although I initialized my `BluetoothAdapter` to `null` and it's a global `private` to the class.

Comment: Yup still not working. Could you try writing the same two 3 lines of code inside your `MainActivity` to see if you get the error

Comment: Okay, so I tried it just as you have it and it works fine. So, I'm not sure what is happening with yours.  If you hover over `bluetoothAdapter` with your mouse does it give you any suggestions? Also, maybe post more of your code? Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse with ADT?

Comment: I figured it out. I just needed inside a block